# How to update and delete data from table?

Tags: php, codeigniter, crud

I'm new to codeigniter and I want to update and delete a data from the table. Can someone help solve this?I've tried other options but wasn't successful.

Here's my view:

```
    <script>
        function show_confirm(act) {
            if (act == "edit")
                var r = confirm("Do you really want to edit this?");

            else 
                var r = confirm("Do you really want to delete this?");

            if (r==true){
                window.location="<?php echo base_url(); ?>site/"+act;
            }
        }
    </script>
    <style>

        select{
            position: absolute;
            left: 35%;
            height: 5%;
            width: 33%;
            border-radius: 5px;
            font-family: arial;
        }

        table {
            background: #333;
            width: 700px;
            border-collapse: 1px;
            font-family: arial;
            position: absolute;
            top: 33%;
            left: 25%;
            color: #777;
        }

        th {
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
        }

        td {
            background: #999;
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        .data {
            color: #555;
        }

        .data:hover {
            background: #FFF;
        }

        #action {
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #444;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        #action:hover {
            color: #FFF;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="menu">
            <h1 class="sis">SIS</h1>
            <p class="welcome">Welcome!&nbsp &nbsp| &nbsp</p>
            <p class="logout"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p>
            <nav class="navi">
              <ul>
                  <li><a href="home">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">About</a>
                        <ul class="about">
                            <li><a href="vismis">Vision/Mission</a></li>
                            <li><a href="history">History</a></li>
                        </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="admission">Admission</a></li>
                  <li><a href="calendar">Calendar</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Students</a>
                        <ul class="stud">
                            <li><a href="gradeI">Grade I</a></li>
                            <li><a href="gradeII">Grade II</a></li>
                            <li><a href="gradeIII">Grade III</a></li>
                            <li><a href="gradeIV">Grade IV</a></li>
                            <li><a href="gradeV">Grade V</a></li>
                            <li><a href="gradeVI">Grade VI</a></li>
                            <li><a href="acadrecs">Academic Records</a></li>
                        </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Teachers</a>
                        <ul class="teach">
                            <li><a href="#">Gradesheet</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Lesson Plan</a></li>
                        </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <header>
      <div class="container">

            <select>
                <option placeholder="section"></option>
                <option value="section">Section I</option>
                <option value="section">Section II</option>
                <option value="section">Section III</option>
                <option value="section">Section IV</option>
                <option value="section">Section V</option>
                <option value="section">Section VI</option>
            </select>

            <table>
                <tr id="field">
                    <th scope="col"> ID </th>
                    <th scope="col"> First Name </th>
                    <th scope="col"> Last Name </th>
                    <th scope="col"> Contact # </th>
                    <th scope="col"> Address </th>
                    <th scope="col" colspan="2"> Action </th>
                </tr>

                <?php foreach ($user_list as $u_key) { ?>

                <tr class="data" >
                    <td><?php echo $u_key->ID; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $u_key->FNAME; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $u_key->LNAME; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $u_key->CONTACT; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $u_key->ADDRESS; ?></td>
                    <td width="40" align="left"><a id="action" href="#" onClick="show_confirm('edit',<?php echo $u_key->ID; ?>)">Edit</a></td>
                    <td width="40" align="left"><a id="action" href="#" onClick="show_confirm('delete',<?php echo $u_key->ID; ?>)">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>

                <?php } ?>

            </table>

      </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

My Controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Site extends CI_Controller {
public function index(){
    $this->home();
    $this->load->helper('url');
}

public function home(){
    $data['title'] = "Home";
    $this->load->view("view_main");
}

function vismis(){
    $data['title'] = "Vismis";
    $this->load->view("view_vismis");
}

function history(){
    $data['title'] = "History";
    $this->load->view("view_history");
}

function admission(){
    $data['title'] = "Admission";
    $this->load->view("view_admission");
}

function contact(){
    $data['title'] = "Contact";
    $this->load->view("view_contact");
}

function calendar($year = null, $month = null){

    $data['title'] = "Calendar";

    if(!$year) {
        $year = date('Y');
    }

    if(!$month) {
        $month = date('m');
    }

    $this->load->model('cal_model');

    if ($day = $this->input->post('day')) {
        $this->cal_model->add_cal_data(
            "$year-$month-$day", 
            $this->input->post('data')
            );
    }

    $data['calendar'] = $this->cal_model->generate($year, $month);

    $this->load->view("view_calendar",$data);

}

public function gradeI(){

    $this->load->model('stud_model');

    $data['title'] = "gradeI";

    $data['user_list'] = $this->stud_model->get_users();

    $this->load->view('view_students', $data);

}

function add_stud(){
    $this->load->model('stud_model');

    $udata['fname'] = $this->input->post('fname');
    $udata['lname'] = $this->input->post('lname');
    $udata['contact'] = $this->input->post('contact');
    $udata['address'] = $this->input->post('address');

    $res = $this->stud_model->insert_user_to_db($udata);

    if ($res){
        header('location:'.base_url()."site/gradeI");
    }
}

public function edit() {

    $this->load->model('stud_model');

    $data['title'] = "edit";

    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);

    $data['user'] = $this->stud_model->getById($id);

    $this->load->view('view_editstud', $data);

}

public function update_stud() {

    $mdata['fname'] = $_POST['fname'];
    $mdata['lname'] = $_POST['lname'];
    $mdata['contact'] = $_POST['contact'];
    $mdata['address'] = $_POST['address'];

    $res = $this->stud_model->update_info($mdata, $_POST['id']);

    if($res) {
        header('location'.base_url()."site/gradeI");
    }

}

public function delete() {
    $this->load->model('stud_model');

    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);

    $res = $this->stud_model->del_stud($id);

    if ($res) {
        header('location:'.base_url()."site/gradeI");
    }
}

function gradeII(){

    $this->load->model('stud_model');

    $data['title'] = "gradeII";

    $data['user_list'] = $this->stud_model->get_users();

    $this->load->view('view_stud_two',$data);
}

function gradeIII(){
    $data['title'] = "gradeIII";
    $this->load->view('view_students');
}

function gradeIV(){
    $data['title'] = "gradeIV";
    $this->load->view('view_students');
}

function gradeV(){
    $data['title'] = "gradeV";
    $this->load->view('view_students');
}

function gradeVI(){
    $data['title'] = "gradeVI";
    $this->load->view('view_students');
}

function acadrecs(){
    $data['title'] = "acadrecs";
    $this->load->view('view_acadrecs');
}

public function enroll(){
    $data['title'] = "enroll";
    $this->load->view('view_enroll');
}

}
```

and my Model:

```
<?php

class Stud_model extends CI_Model
{


function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database("sis");
}

public function get_users() {

    $query = $this->db->get('students');

    return $query->result();

}

public function insert_user_to_db($udata) {

    return $this->db->insert('students', $udata);

}

public function getById($id) {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('students', array('id'=>$id));
    return $query->row_array();
}

public function update_info($data, $id) {

    $this->db->where('ID', $id);
    return $this->db->update('students', $data);

}

public function del_stud($id) {

    $this->db->where('ID', $id);
    return $this->db->delete('students');

}
}
```

nothing happens when I click on delete.

On the edit link...

The view:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>site/update_stud">

    <?php extract($user); ?>

    <table>

        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Enter your first name</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="fname" size="20" value="<?php echo $fname; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Enter your last name</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="lname" size="20" value="<?php echo $lname; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Enter your contact number</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="contact" size="20" value="<?php echo $contact; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Enter your address</th>
            <td><textarea name="address" rows="5" cols="20"><?php echo $address; ?>      </textarea></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" /></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

This error will show up:

> Enter your first name  A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: fname
>
> Filename: views/view_editstud.php
>
> Line Number: 60
>
> " />

and so on with other input types.

Comment: be more specific.... what error you got?

Comment: It is very difficult to read lengthy code. Just show the code which is not working as expected.

Comment: This may not directly answer your question, but: 1) I don't think there's a need to ask the user to confirm the edit, since all you do when user does confirm, is serve up the edit view (nothing edited at this point). 2) I would strongly advise against facilitating a delete method which is accessible via the url (get) - use post instead...

Comment: sorry about that. nothing happens when I click on the delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, neither of the javascript confirm links will work because you're not actually passing the id through with the `act`:

```
<script>
    function show_confirm(act, id) {

        if (act == "edit") {
            var r = confirm("Do you really want to edit this?");
        } else {
            var r = confirm("Do you really want to delete this?");
        }

        //Just FYI, the above can be written like this:
        //var r = (act == 'edit') ? confirm("Do you really want to edit this?") : confirm("Do you really want to delete this?");
        //or even
        //var r = confirm("Do you really want to "+act+" this?");

        if (r == true) {
            window.location = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>site/" + act + "/" + id;
        }

        //Another FYI, the above could be written like this:
        // !r || window.location = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>site/" + act + "/" + id;
    }
</script>
```

Obviously, you can delete the comments.

Secondly, you don't need to use `$this->uri->segment()` to pass params to a controller method as codeigniter will automatically pass them (Unless you're using `URI ROUTING`), you can instead:

```
public function delete($id)
{
    $this->load->model('stud_model');

    $res = $this->stud_model->del_stud($id);

    //There is no point in this if statement as it will just display a 
    //blank page if $res evaluates to FALSE
    if ($res) {
        //As you aren't using a variable below you might as well use single quotes
        //Also, instead of using header('Location') you should use redirect() with codeiginiter
        redirect('site/gradeI');
    }
}
```

Lastly, you should really think about validation e.g. codeigniters built in `Form_validation` Library.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Ross! I'm still trying to understand how codeigniter works. Another thing is my edit link displays the page but it has errors in it. I'm guessing it's about the variable. Can you help me with it?

Comment: I added it at the bottom of my post.

Comment: Essentially, this error will be shown when you're using a variable that PHP doesn't know about (it's not been declared), however, you'll need to show me `view_editstud.php` as well so that I can see what's going on on the page.

Comment: Firstly, I personally wouldn't use `extract()` as it's perceived as being bad practice and can make debugging code harder especially further down the line. `var_dump($user);die();` before the line with `extract($user)` on to see if what's meant to be in `$user` is actually there. Thirdly, check out https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html (mainly for the `set_value()` function) ...you might also like the HTML Table library as well.

Comment: I put var_dump and this will appear: object(CI_DB_mysql_result)#17 (8) { ["conn_id"]=> resource(29) of type (mysql link persistent) ["result_id"]=> resource(32) of type (mysql result) ["result_array"]=> array(0) { } ["result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["custom_result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["current_row"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["row_data"]=> NULL }

Comment: I also removed extract and changed it to foreach and then a new error will appear: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$fname

Filename: views/view_editstud.php

Line Number: 60

Comment: If you're getting a `CI_DB_mysql_result`  it means you're not actually get the result out of the object ie you need to use `$query->row()` or '$query->result()'. Also, you should really look at using the `form_validation` library in codeigniter.